# Isolating span title from span using BeautifulsSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following

```
<h3>The price of something is <span title="60,487">60.5k</span></h3>
```

I want to get the title from the span. How is that accomplished? This span title is dynamic and changes from the website.

Comment: How is this `span` different from other `span` in your document? Is this span the only span with the `title` attribute?

Comment: On the whole website, no it isn't. Until now i have isolated the above code, so in what I am working with it is the only title tag. But in this case it is 60,487 that I want

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. What makes this `span` tag special? Is is because it is inside `h3` and has a `title` attribute?

Comment: On the whole webside there is only one h3 tag, so yes it is special of that reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [CSS selectors.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """<h3>The price of something is <span title="60,487">60.5k</span></h3>"""
>>> soup = BS(html, "html.parser")
>>> soup.select_one("h3 > span[title]").get("title")
'60,487'
```